# json REST api の仕様で、機械的に処理できるものはある？

Tags: rest

json の api をひたすら記述していると、いちいち仕様ページをみにいかなくても、形式データを提供してもらって、一括で api 処理を実装したくなります。

#### 質問

REST + json な api サーバーの仕様記述において、機械的に処理可能な形式で記述できるものはありますか？いくつかあったとして、何がよく使われていますか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

この回答は今後の情勢で変わる可能性はありますが、現在のところ[Swagger](https://swagger.io/) / [Open API](https://www.openapis.org/) がデファクトスタンダードになりつつあります。

Swaggerをベースに、RESTful APIの記述標準化を目指す「Open API Initiative」が[2015年に立ち上げ](https://www.publickey1.jp/blog/15/open_api_initiative.html)られました。

Swaggerの中身の説明は[Qiita等の投稿](https://qiita.com/gcyata/items/342073fa7607fd4082bd)に譲るとして、マシンリーダブルな仕様(Spec)からクライアント・サービスのコードを自動生成、その逆でコードからSpecの生成といったToolchainの世界が実現されています。

XML WebサービスにもあったSOAPみたいなものです。